# How can I make a list of a input string the user has typed into Python?

Tags: python, arrays, string, list, numbers

I'm new in programming and in my script I have to create a list with a input string y the user.

I know how basic of slicing works and making a list ex:  list = []

but I need to write the code so that each word in the string that was typed becomes a set number in the list.

ex:  If the user prints,  Hello my name is

in the list it has to to be    hello my, name, is   hello is = 1  my = 2  name = 3  is = 4

then I have to take the first letter out of every word that was placed in that list???

can someone please help???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [32]: L = input("Enter a sentence: ").split()
Enter a sentence: Hello my name is

In [33]: L
Out[33]: ['Hello', 'my', 'name', 'is']

In [34]: L[0]
Out[34]: 'Hello'

In [35]: L[1]
Out[35]: 'my'

In [36]: for i in range(len(L)):
   ....:     print(i, L[i])
   ....:     
0 Hello
1 my
2 name
3 is


In [37]: firsts = [i[0] for i in L]

In [38]: firsts
Out[38]: ['H', 'm', 'n', 'i']
```

Comment: yes i see you made a list and split it but  i need to take out each  letter of every word of the string?

Answer (score 0):

So what i understand , you want to get the first charcter of each word in the list

Here is quick solution.

```
>>> x = 'Hello my name is'
>>> new_list = x.split(' ')
>>> new_list
['Hello', 'my', 'name', 'is']
>>> [i[0] for i in new_list]
['H', 'm', 'n', 'i']
>>>
```

Comment: ok I understand that you split the string in the second line then made a new_list variable but after that I don't understand??? whats [i[0] 
I see you made a for loop for the new variable?

This is what I have so far

def acronym():

   
    usrInput = input("Please type what you want to turn into a acronym:",)
    newInput = usrInput.split()
    
    for i in newInput:

acronym()

Answer (score 0):

if you need more pythonic style, basically its the same as @inspectorg4dget's answer

```
>>> first_char = [word[0] for word in raw_input("Enter a sentence : ").split()]
Enter a sentence : Hello my name is
>>> first_char
['H', 'm', 'n', 'i']
>>>
```